# Transformation of objects to different coordinate sets

Tags: java, camera, rotation, graphics2d

I am using a tree structure of objects to control my 2D world of objects. The root element or camera contains a list of sub objects, in this case a simple "hand" object. The hand object contains a list of sub objects which are 5 card objects.

Now the hand object is rotated 90 degrees. The Card objects' x position is increasing. So the result when you view it on the screen is that the cards appear to be building downwards (because the hand object is rotated)

Eventually I will need a card object to transfer to another hand object and I want to do that with smooth animation, so I need to map the card object to the camera's world, but so that it doesn't look like it moved.

For example, let's say one of the card objects has an X position of 100 with a y position of 0. When I rotate the hand object 90 degrees, it appears as if the card object is 0 in the x dimension and 100 in the y position.

If I simply remove the card from the hand and add it to the camera, then the card rotates back and moves in the x position appearing at 100,0.

For all rotations and positions (and scalings) how can I transfer the card object to the camera object and keep it's position on the screen?

In the code below, if the 'g' is pressed, I attempt to remove a card from the hand and add it to the camera. I call a method called 'transformObjectToTheseCoords' but I don't think my math is right...

```
public void update(LinkedList<Object> messages)
    {
        super.update(messages);

        if(messages.size() > 0 && messages.get(0) instanceof KeyEvent)
        {
            KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent)messages.get(0);

            if(ke.getKeyChar() == 'g')
            {
                if(super.getSubObjects().size() > 0)
                {
                    GameObject o = super.getSubObjects().remove(0);

                    GameObject parent = o.getParentObject();

                    while(parent != camera)
                    {
                        parent.transformObjectToTheseCoords(o);
                        parent = parent.getParentObject();
                    }   
                    camera.addSubObject(o);
                }
            }
        }       
    }
```

---

```
public void transformObjectToTheseCoords(GameObject o)
    {
        o.xPos += xPos;
        o.yPos += yPos;
        o.rPos += rPos;
    }
```

---

If anyone has another technique to use, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to work with AffineTransform matrices... this appropriately handles the x and y transformations between different coordinate sets.

```
@Override
    public void update(LinkedList<Object> messages)
    {
        super.update(messages);

        if(messages.size() > 0 && messages.get(0) instanceof KeyEvent)
        {
            KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent)messages.get(0);

            if(ke.getKeyChar() == 'g')
            {
                if(super.getSubObjects().size() > 0)
                {
                    GameObject o = super.getSubObjects().remove(0);                 

                    //We are inside the position layout, so first let's transform the object to these coordinates...
                    o.setRotationPosition(this.rPos);
                    //It's x,y position are relative to this already, so don't need to change that...
                    //Now the next layer up is the camera, so let's calculate the new X and Y

                    float x = (float) ((Math.cos(this.rPos)*o.getXPosition())-(Math.sin(this.rPos)*o.getYPosition())+this.xPos);
                    float y = (float) ((Math.sin(this.rPos)*o.getXPosition())+(Math.cos(this.rPos)*o.getYPosition())+this.yPos);

                    o.setPosition(x, y);
                    camera.addSubObject(o);


                }
            }
        }       
    }
```